# Divergence and the determination of what values of p a series is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I just did my calculus exam today and there was 2 questions that I couldn't figure out! The questions that I couldn't answer were all related to the series.

The first one was something around that we have to show that the series is divergent and that its terms approach $0$ as $n\to\infty$. I totally get how to show that it is divergent but I am not sure how to do the 2nd part of the question, that its terms approach $0$. How do I show that?

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$

---

The second question was asking to find what values of $p$ this series was convergent. I actually just don't really understand this question. Should I just put $p=0$ and apply the integral test?

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n^p}$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. The function  $\ln $ is continuous at $1$, $1+ \frac{1}{n} \to 1$, hence $\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \to \ln (1) =0.$
2. For each $p>0$, the sequence $\frac{1}{n^p} \to 0$ and is decreasing. Now invoke Leibniz ! It is your turn to investigate the case $p \le 0.$